Is there a solution for implementing "Sign in with Google" functionality using AWS Federated Sign-In in a Chrome extension?
The Chrome extension is not allowing the redirection of the URL to a new tab for login and then redirecting back to my extension. I am facing an issue where after initiating the Google login process, the redirect back to my extension is being blocked or not functioning as expected.
This issue prevents the completion of the authentication flow and disrupts the user experience. I haven't found a solution to address this problem yet. Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
